# how to prevent assigning class to view in storyboard from hiding subviews?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am trying to add viewB as a subview of viewA in the storyboard interface builder. When I assign a custom class to viewA in the storyboard, all of its subviews (including viewB) become invisible. I want viewA to contain shared visual elements and be able to add other elements to each instance as subviews.

viewA is loaded from a xib, so I am thinking maybe when I assign the class it is redrawing itself from the xib over the subviews? I can see the subviews fine if I temporarily remove the class assignment

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking - do the views disappear in the storyboard or when you run the app. When you put an instance of `ViewA` in a storyboard scene, it isn't going to be loaded from a XIB file at runtime. The instantiation process will call `init(coder:)`.

Comment: hey, in both of these cases the views disappear. I am a little bit confused by the second part, in the custom class init(coder:) calls a function that loads a nib from the bundle.

Comment: Ok.  If you load from the NIB in `init(coder:)` then it should be OK. Does `ViewA` declare itself as `@IBDesignable`?  Since your view disappears in both cases I would suggest that there is either something wrong with your code or with your constraints.

Comment: yes, it is @IBDesignable. just to clarify, viewA, the instance of the custom class, does not disappear. it renders correctly according to the xib. the problem is that the subviews that are added to that view in the storyboard (non in the xib) disappear when I set viewA's class

Comment: I want to be able to instantiate views of my custom class in different places in the storyboard then add other subviews to those views

Comment: So it renders correctly in the storyboard until you add subviews?  Some code or screenshots or something could help clarify your problem.